Module source root type com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.facet.ndk.NativeSourceRootType is not registered as JpsModelSerializerExtension
I'm new to here. Sorry for my bad English.
I just tried to build empty project named Game Activity (C++) using Android Studio Meerkat | 2024.3.1 Canary 2 and got this error.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module source root type com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.facet.ndk.NativeSourceRootType@xxxxxx is not registered as JpsModelSerializerExtension
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Basically I search the error descriptions with Google. This doesn't exit at all.
It seems that the problem is kotlin and ndk. I don't know.
What is JpsModelSerializerExtension?
What should I do for it?
Help please.
I searched Google for an hour.
I expect to get how to fix the settings of Android studio, and the project built successfully.

How can the issue be kotlin and ndk? Can you share the most relevant code and configurations.

I solved it by disabling the Android SDK Support plugin.
Go to Settings -> Plugins -> Installed -> Uncheck the Android SDK Support plugin.

Issue #378453263 has solved:
Update:
Android Studio Meerkat | 2024.3.1 Canary 3
Android Gradle Plugin 8.9.0-alpha03

This could be a comment
